# Ripple Effect on BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add Ripple Effect like this in BottomTabNavigator but don't know how?
[image]

I'm using [createMaterialBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html) for BottomTabNavigator.

Comment: what's the question ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the Material Bottom Tab Navigator to change color you need to use the `tabBarColor` property of the `navigationOptions` for each tab. You can see this in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbarcolor). You also need to set `shifting` to be true in the navigator's `config` if you want the ripple effect.

You will need to make sure that you have the following dependencies installed:

- `react-navigation`
- `react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs`
- `react-native-paper`
- `react-native-vector-icons`, though if using Expo this is not required as it is already included

For more details on the dependencies that you need see the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html)

Here is a sample navigator:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs'; // <- notice where we import createMaterialBottomTabNavigator from
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const tabBarIcon = name => ({ tintColor }) => (
  <MaterialIcons
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
    name={name}
    color={tintColor}
    size={24}
  />
);

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('photo-album'),
      tabBarColor: 'blue' // <- set this to the color you want
    }
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('favorite'),
      tabBarColor: 'green' // <- set this to the color you want
    }
  }
};

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
  shifting: true,  // <- notice this has been set to true
  activeColor: 'white',
  inactiveColor: 'black'
};

const MainNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(screens, config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

I would have created a snack to show this working but unfortunately `react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs` doesn't play nice in a snack, but it does play nice in a local `Expo` or `react-native` app.

Comment: If I use this, can I remove the `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` dependencies?

Comment: @arahpanah yes you can